# Structuring Firebase Database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following [this](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) tutorial to structure Firebase data. Near the end, it says the following:

> With this kind of structure, you should keep in mind to update the data at 2 locations under the user and group too. Also, I would like to notify you that everywhere on the Internet, the object keys are written like "user1","group1","group2" etc. where as in practical scenarios it is better to use firebase generated keys which look like '-JglJnGDXcqLq6m844pZ'. We should use these as it will facilitate ordering and sorting.

So based on that, I'm assuming that the final result should be the following:

[image]

[image]

I'm using [this python wrapper](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database) to post the data.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you write data to a Firebase array (for example in Javascript) using a line like this

```
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

var updates = {item1: value1, item2: value2};

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Like is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields), you will get a generated key for data "pushed". In the example above `newPostKey` will contain this generated key

**UPDATE**
To answer the updated question with with the Python wrapper:
Look for the section "Saving Data" in the page you linked to.

The code would look something like this;

```
data = {"Title": "The Animal Book"}
book = db.child("AllBooks").push(data)

data = {"Title": "Animals"}
category = db.child("Categories").push(data)

data = {category['name']: true }
db.child("AllBooks").child(book['name']).child("categories").push(data)
```